# show convergence for x tending to zero for $(2 - a^{1/x})^x$

Tags: limits, derivatives

I have the following problem:

I need to show whether a limit exists for $F(x) = (2 - a^{1/x})^x$ for $x$ tending towards zero (and $x$ tending towards infinity) where $0<a<1$. If one of these limits exists I am supposed to calculate it.

Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

I already tried expressing $F(x)$ as a Summation according to the binomial theorem and calculating the limit of the series but without any luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Note that if the limit exists, then
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} F(x)
 = \exp\left(\ln \left( \lim_{x \to 0} F(x) \right)\right)
 = \exp\left(\lim_{x \to 0} \ln ( F(x) )\right).
$$